# What are the different size of images needed for application background ? (except icon bar)

Tags: android, android-background

I want to add image as a background to application (- Action bar).

What are the 5 sizes of Image I will have to produce to give to developer.

Here is background Image that I need. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmzSu.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
xxxhdpi 1280x1696
xxhdpi  960x1432
xhdpi   640x484
hdpi    480x716
mdpi    320x424
ldpi    240x278
```